# How to retrieve IP address from DNS response message

Tags: java, dns

I have been trying to program DNS  request-reply for a small project. Here is the DNS request message   `de42010000010000000000000377777706676f6f676c6503636f6d0000010001` that I am sending to query the ip address for `www.google.com`. The server I am requesting to is `141.26.64.1`. I managed to get the response packet. But I am not sure how to  retrieve the IP address from the resonse array of bytes. I found an example on the internet which assumes that the last four bytes of the response contains the resolved IP address. Is it always true? Or from which bit location the 4 bytes of the resolved IP starts. For the time being I don't want to go into the finest details of DNS response datagram because I am trying to keep my code as simple as possible. So I just want to know if there is a specific bit location where those 4-bytes bigin.
Thanx in advance

Comment: The DNS protocol itself is heavily documented; you should try and pick the packet format and start from there

Comment: How are you doing the DNS request?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a specific location where the IP address in the DNS answer is stored. There are can be multiple kinds of records in an DNS response like CNAME, A, NX. The IP address is stored in an "A" record. There can also be an "Additional" and "Authority" sections. You need to parse the entire datagram according to the [DNS protocol](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1035.txt). Look at the 4th section in that document.

If you want to keep your code simple or do it efficiently, you should consider using a library for this.